# Ошибка в использовании метода append строки

Tags: c++, массивы, строки

```
string findNewString(string a)
{
    //делаем из строки символьный массив
    const char *mas_of_char = a.c_str();

    //длина нашего массива
    int size = strlen(mas_of_char);

    //искомая строка
    string ourstring("");

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (mas_of_char[i] == '*' && mas_of_char[i + 1] == '*')
        {
            for (int k = i + 2; k < size; k++)
            {
                if (mas_of_char[k] == '*')
                {
                    for (int z = i; z < k; z++)
                        if (z = k - 1)
                            ourstring.append(mas_of_char[z]);//здесь выдает ошибку
                }
            }
            return ourstring;
        }
        else return "no";

    }
```

нужно найти подцепочку, начинающуюся с префикса `**` и заканчивающуюся суффиксом `*`. когда использую `append()`, он выдает: отсутствуют экземпляры, соответствующие списку аргументов. (аргументы: const char)

Comment: В первую очередь `if (z = k - 1)` - не срравнение, а присваивание, которое всегда выполняется успешно и возвращает true, вместо собственно результата сравнения. Измените, проверьте заново. Также приведите полностью текст ошибки и название и версию компилятора.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

У класса `string` нет перегруженной функции *append*, которая принимала бы один аргумент `char` [Документация](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/basic_string.html).
Мы должны использовать вот эту перегрузку

```
std::string::append(size_type _Count, char _Ch)
```

Можно заменить `ourstring.append(mas_of_char[z])` на `ourstring.append(1, mas_of_char[z])`

Либо вместо функции *append* используйте

```
ourstring += mas_of_char[z]
```

Answer (score 0):

Когда вы пробегаетесь по циклу необходимо учитывать возможность выхода за пределы массива. Допустим, если '**' встретится на конце строки, то получите `undefined behavior`. Также как уже было сказано, необходимо заменить условие `if (z = k - 1)`.

Поскольку используете c++, то я бы советовал воспользоваться стандартными средствами класса `std::string`. Вот мой пример:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

std::string findSubString(const std::string& source);

int main() {
    std::string a = "test**substring*end";
    std::cout << "Source: " << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Substring: " << findSubString(a) << std::endl;

    a = "**substring";
    std::cout << "Source: " << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Substring: " << findSubString(a) << std::endl;

    a = "test**substr*ing*";
    std::cout << "Source: " << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Substring: " << findSubString(a) << std::endl;

    a = "test*substr**";
    std::cout << "Source: " << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Substring: " << findSubString(a) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

std::string findSubString(const std::string& source) {
    const char* startDelimiter = "**";
    const char* endDelimiter = "*";
    size_t pos = source.find(startDelimiter);
    if (pos == std::string::npos) {
        return "no";
    }

    size_t startPosSubString = pos + strlen(startDelimiter);
    size_t endPosSubString = source.find(endDelimiter, startPosSubString);
    if (endPosSubString == std::string::npos) {
        return "no";
    } else {
        return source.substr(startPosSubString, endPosSubString - startPosSubString);
    }
}
```

Результат выполнения:

```
Source: test**substring*end
Substring: substring
Source: **substring
Substring: no
Source: test**substr*ing*
Substring: substr
Source: test*substr**
Substring: no
```

И также стоит пересмотреть возвращаемую строку, если результат не найден, поскольку 'no' может встретиться между вашими разделителями.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код, не говоря уж о том, что он некорректный, вообще не имеет смысла. Например, что делает данный цикл?

```
for (int z = i; z < k; z++)
    if (z = k - 1)
        ourstring.append(mas_of_char[z]);//здесь выдает
```

Во-первых, в if предложении у вас используется присваивание `=`  вместо, как я понимаю, сравнения `==`

```
    if (z = k - 1)
         ^^^
```

Но даже если заменить присваивание на сравнение, то в этом цикле, при условии правильного написания вызова метода `append`  в объекте `ourstring` будет предпринята попытка сохранить только один символ перед символом `'*'`.

И, вообще, если вы имеете дело со строкой, то незачем переводить ее в символьный массив. Следует иметь дело с методами, которые предоставляет класс `std::string`.

Если я понял вас правильно, то все, что вам нужно, это следующее

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string findNewString( const std::string &s )
{
    std::string t;

    std::string::size_type pos = s.find( "**" );

    if ( pos != std::string::npos ) 
    {
        std::string::size_type n = s.find( '*', pos + 2 );
        if ( n != std::string::npos ) t.assign( s, pos, n + 1 - pos );
    }

    return t;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "\"" << findNewString( "12**345*" ) << "\"" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\"" << findNewString( "12**345" ) << "\"" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\"" << findNewString( "12***" ) << "\"" << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
"**345*"
""
"***"
```

То есть функция возвращает подстроку, начинающуюся с префикса "**" и заканчивающуюся суффиксом `"*"` включительно. Если либо префикс, либо суффикс не найдены, то возвращается пустая строка.